# Наложение изображений на слой

Tags: изображения, unity3d

Предположим на канвасе есть слой в виде Image, занимающий ~75% экрана. Также вне канваса есть несколько различных изображений тоже типа Image, но разного размера. Есть ли в Unity встроенная возможность накладывать их на слой, подгоняя по размеру? Это при условии, что разрешения могут быть разные.

Comment: приложите картинку как есть и как надо чтобы было, а то пока из ваших объяснений мало что понятно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не смотря на всю кривизну заданного вопроса, я думаю, что я его понял.

1. Можешь поставить canvasScaler в режим Match Width and Height и там поставить ползунок на середину.
2. После чего правильно настроить анхоры на всех элементах канваса.

и получишь именно то, что тебе нужно. Это самый легкий способ.

Но он породит много трудностей если у тебя на канвасе есть элементы текста. Увы, это слабое место юнити.

Элегантного способа добится того же самого без проблем с текстом я увы, не нашел.

Но я на днях подбирал хаки для фикса проблем с текстом в даном режиме. Вот я сложил список:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1226551/ui-text-is-blurred-unity-535f.html